# pulling min and max values from list of list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of projects called `projects` and a list of tasks called `tasks` associated with each project.  Some projects don't have tasks and some tasks have not yet been completed. some projects also have multiple tasks. I would like to generate a list of lists that shows each project, the earliest task start date and latest task end date. If a task hasn't been complete, there should be `None` for the end date. If a project has no tasks there should be `None` for start and end date.

My code yields the wrong results, so I would like to know why, but also see if anyone has recommendations for a more efficient method of doing this.

Format of tasks:

[Project ID, Start Date, End Date]

My Code:

```
import datetime
tasks = [['ID1', datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 1), datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 2)],
       ['ID1', datetime.datetime( 2015, 10, 1), None],
       ['ID2', datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 1), datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 3)]]

projects = [['ID1'], ['ID2'], ['ID3']]

for key, item in enumerate(projects):
    if item[0] not in tasks:
         item.append(None)
         item.append(None)
    else:
        start_date = [x[1:-1] for x in tasks if x[0] == item[0]]
        item.append(min(start_date))
        end_date = [x[-1] for x in tasks if x[0] == item[0]]
        if end_date.count(None) <> 0: #checks to see if there is a None value
            item.append(None)
        else:
            item.append(max(end_date))


print projects
```

My Output:

```
[['ID1', None, None], ['ID2', None, None], ['ID3', None, None]]
```

Desired Output:

```
[['ID1', datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 1), None], ['ID2', datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 1), datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 3)], ['ID3', None, None]]
```

Comment: I would have used tuples for the tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in the line

```
if item[0] not in tasks:
```

because this checks whether or not the string 'IDx' is a member of the tasks list. However, tasks is a lists of lists - so it will not contain the string "directly".

My recommendation would be to change tasks to a dictionary - like

```
tasks = {'ID1': [datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 1), datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 2)],
   'ID1': [datetime.datetime( 2015, 10, 1), None],
   'ID2': [datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 1), datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 3)]}
```

if you do not have millions of entries, this should be as fast, but checking for entries is easier, and more intuitive.
The idea is that you can check `'ID1' in tasks`, and it will return `True` - because the in check, done on a dictionary, does so on the keys defining the dict's access, i.e. the IDs in the example of a dict given above.

The complete solution could look like this:

```
import datetime
tasks = {'ID1':[[datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 1), datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 2)], [datetime.datetime( 2015, 10, 1), None]],
     'ID2':[[datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 1), datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 3)]]
    }

projects = [['ID1'], ['ID2'], ['ID3']]

for key, item in enumerate(projects):
if item[0] not in tasks:
    item.append(None)
    item.append(None)
else:
    start_date = [x[0] for x in tasks[item[0]]]
    if start_date.count(None) != 0: #checks to see if there is a None value
        item.append(None)
    else:
        item.append(min(start_date))
    end_date = [x[1] for x in tasks[item[0]]]
    if end_date.count(None) != 0: #checks to see if there is a None value
        item.append(None)
    else:
        item.append(max(end_date))


print projects
```

The output is:

```
[['ID1', datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0), None], ['ID2', datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 3, 0, 0)], ['ID3', None, None]]
```

If you want to go to dictionaries completely, i.e. including the projects-data, this would be the answer:

```
import datetime
tasks = {'ID1':[[datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 1), datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 2)], [datetime.datetime( 2015, 10, 1), None]],
         'ID2':[[datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 1), datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 3)]]
        }

projects = [['ID1'], ['ID2'], ['ID3']]
projects_dict = {}

for key, item in enumerate(projects):
    projects_dict[item[0]] = []
    if item[0] not in tasks:
        projects_dict[item[0]].append(None)
        projects_dict[item[0]].append(None)
    else:
        start_date = [x[0] for x in tasks[item[0]]]
        if start_date.count(None) != 0: #checks to see if there is a None value
            projects_dict[item[0]].append(None)
        else:
            projects_dict[item[0]].append(min(start_date))
        end_date = [x[1] for x in tasks[item[0]]]
        if end_date.count(None) != 0: #checks to see if there is a None value
            projects_dict[item[0]].append(None)
        else:
            projects_dict[item[0]].append(max(end_date))


print projects_dict
```

Oh, and the result of the dict-only approach (which would be preferred, I think) is:

```
{'ID2': [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 3, 0, 0)], 'ID3': [None, None], 'ID1': [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0), None]}
```

EDIT: fyi - a general way to convert lists of lists to dicts in Python is (the following is not the most concise, but it is the most easily understandable):

```
dictionary = {}
for list in list_of_lists:
    dictionary[list[0]] = list[1:]
```

Comment: I see the issue now, thank you. How do I resolve it? The dictionary sounds good but I'm not sure how to integrate with the rest of the code. Could you include that in your answer?

Comment: This is super helpful! I selected it as the best answer, but it looks like a whole section needs to be indented in the first complete answer!

Comment: No problem! If you want to learn more on dictionaries, try the official documentation (which is superb, try go there first if you have python questions) [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html). Additionally, [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) appears to be a decent  tutorial on dicts:

Comment: Can you please update your answer to show how to go from a list of list to the dictionary you are using? My list of list comes from a database, so I need to convert, but am havng trouble doing so even with the documentation

Answer (score 0):

The easiest correction here is to replace the line:

```
if item[0] not in tasks:
```

with something like:

```
if not any((item[0] in x for x in tasks))
```

Using a dictionary, like @cleros suggests, is a better approach if that works with the rest of your code, especially if the `ID`s really are more like keys rather than just the first element of the list.

Also, the approach I suggest is inefficient, but that isn't always important.  If efficiency is important, you could also create an intermediate list or set to check from `tasks` using

```
task_keys = [task[0] for task in tasks]
```

and then:

```
item[0] not in task_keys
```

(Aside: there are a number of problems below the `else` to, so don't be surprised if things don't work straight away once this line is fixed.)

Comment: I implemented your first solution and the other problems became apparent. I fixed these issues in the original code. Could you show in your answer the dictionary solution? I new to python and don't fully understand them.